# Django for Everybody CSS Autograder assignment stuck on trying to make replica page

Tags: html, css, django, dom, css-selectors

I have been trying to complete this assignment. I have completed the majority of it but I am stuck of the DJ4E sign. If you use the link below you will see what it is meant to look like.

Specifics I am stuck on:

1. How to remove the purple from from DJ4E text ( it is a link ) so now purple since the link has been visited.
2. DJ4E should be just above the boxes ( see link for pic)

**Here is the link to the assignment:** https://www.dj4e.com/assn/css/index.php

**HTML code (not meant to change):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Blocks</title>
 <!-- Do not change this file - add your CSS styling
      rules to the blocks.css file included below -->
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="blocks.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="one">
Turns out you have a really fun time if you
go to work every day and focus on being
silly and funny and happy! - Hannah Murray
</div>

<div id="two">
All you need in this life is ignorance and confidence,
and then success is sure. - Mark Twain
</div>

<div id="three">
Well, if crime fighters fight crime and fire fighters
fight fire, what do freedom fighters fight? They never
mention that part to us, do they? - George Carlin
</div>

<div id="four">
Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events;
small minds discuss people. - Eleanor Roosevelt
</div>

<p id="link">
<a href="https://www.dj4e.com/" target="_blank">
DJ4E
</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**My CSS code that I have developed and can be edited:**

```
#one {
/*correct*/
  position: fixed;
  width: 25%;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid blue;

}


#two {
/*correct*/
  position: fixed;
  width: 25%;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}


#three {
    /*correct*/

  position: fixed;
  width: 25%;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}


#four {
    /*correct*/
  position: fixed;
  width: 25%;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}


#link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 1.64rem;
  background-color: #0A4B33;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Corbel, Avenir, 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', sans-serif;
 color: white;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: -15 ;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    text-decoration-thickness: initial;
    text-decoration-style: initial;
    text-decoration-color: initial;

}
```

My progress as a picture:
[image: CSS progress, see inside the top link for how it should look]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the link colour, you are really wanting to affect the `<a>` tag rather than the surrounding div, so make a new style link:

```
#link a, #link a:visited {
   color:white;
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Use both a and a:visited so the color is white the first time and after you have clicked the link. You can remove the color style from the #link set as it is now redundant.

To place the top boxes lower than the link, simply make their `top` values 50px rather than 5, eg

```
#two {
/*correct*/
  position: fixed;
  width: 25%;
  top: 50px;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, I really appreciate it! That solved it! Have a great day:)